# Use Tensorflow Lite Python bindings without requiring Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, inference

I have the TF Lite library (1.0) built for ARM, and I'd like to be able to interface with it via Python without requiring all of Tensorflow.

Is it possible to build (cross-compile) the Python bindings for Tensorflow Lite without building all of Tensorflow? Is there a way to extract just the TF Lite Python bindings from the build?